# What does re.match('(...),..', string) return?

Tags: python, regex, match

I am new to python and  have a confusion :

```
type = order_change_separate_t
```

what would `re.match('(...)..', type).group(1)` return? Will it return order_change_separate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: I want to understand the logic behind the (...)..
Does it matches the pattern upto _t because only 2 dots are outside the parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

You should use python's interactive shell to try out these things:

```
sgupta-3:~ sgupta$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> type = "order_change_separate_t"
>>> import re
>>> print re.match('(...)..', type).group(1)
ord
```

It prints 'ord'

(...) is the group 1 defined by the capturing group, the 3 dots match ord.

```
print re.match('(.*)..', type).group(1)
```

will return 'order_change_separate'

The above is obviously a very crude and non-extensible way of extracting it out, since it'll only work for 'order_change_separate' followed by exactly 2 characters.

Better way to do it is as user 'aelor' mentioned above, using a quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

it will return `ord`.

as you have only three characters inside `capture group` `()`

if you want `order_change_separate` use this :

```
re.match('(.*?)_.$', type).group(1)
```

this will match everything before the last `underscore followed by a character`